# What is the right approach with Async/Await/Task on function overloading in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a function:

```
    public static async Task DoSomthing(string str1, int num1, bool bool1)
    {
        //Do something.... (This function will not return any value)
    }
```

I want to overload this function so it can be called with other arguments, but this function will basically call the function above.

Now I have 2 choices and I don't know what is the better one (in every aspect from performance to good coding)?

Option 1:

```
    public static Task DoSomething(CustomObject obj)
    {
        return DoSomthing(obj.str, obj.num1, obj.bool1);
    }
```

Option 2:

```
    public static async Task DoSomething(CustomObject obj)
    {
        await DoSomthing(obj.str, obj.num1, obj.bool1);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be executed almost in the same way but for the one with await it will add some overhead because the compiler will create a state machine.

Compiler creates state machine for methods with async-await keywords so when the control flow reaches `await` it is returned to the calling method. The execution of async method continues when the awaited `Task` (or method that returns `Task`) has finished execution.

As there is no code after `await` it is somewhat inadvisable to use `await` in this scenario. You could simply return a `Task`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do option 1 because you only want to return the task witch it's passing.

Personally I prefer to read in the Taskname Async like DoSomthingAsync you you always know what's async and what's sync

```
public static Task DoSomethingAsync(CustomObject obj) 
    // or set the ConfigureAwait to true when you need stuff done on the same thread.
    => DoSomthingAsync(obj.str, obj.num1, obj.bool1).ConfigureAwait(false);
```